# android check if a contact installed an app android (like whatsapp)

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to let my app scan the users contactlist , and display the name of the contacts who also installed the app.

I have no idea where to begin with this . so if someone could help me getting started , that would be apreciated.

grtz

Answer (score 5):

You will need to research [**ContentResolver**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) because you will have to query the database containing the contacts. To do these queries, you will need the URI and column/header names for contacts db which can be found in the [**Contacts**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) class.

You will also **need users to register that they have your app** on your own servers and the **registration will need a piece of information about the user that other users would have in their contacts** (the users phone number, email address, etc).

You will then need to **query a few users at a time from the users contacts for this piece of information (using the ContentResolver and Contacts class)**, pass it to your server (as text) where it will check if they are registered, then send a message back to initial user (and possibly the match) that you found a match.

That's where you should start, and end :)

**Note, you will need these permissions in the Manifest file:**

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is for programming questions. As is such, a post asking for help should **always** provide a description of what you **have already tried**. If you haven't tried anything yet, I highly encourage you to try something, and post when you encounter a problem.

As your question stands now, we don't know what the problem is. Are you having problems scanning a contact list? Or are you having problems trying to figure out if another user has installed the app?

That being said, you will have to maintain a database for your app containing a list of people who have installed your app. When your app is launched on one device, do whatever you need to do to register the user in your database. Due to the nature of a "contact," one person's phone may only have their phone number, email address, or even just a name. This is of course something you will have to deal with in your implementation.